# Add "Feature Image" Option on add new post

Tags: wordpress

I want to add an option to add feature image on add new post page like the image below.

How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the wordpress function `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Just add that line of code in your wordpress functions, and it will allow you to do that.

Read more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails

Hope that helps!

**UPDATE:**  here is what I use in my `functions.php`. It creates re-sized versions of your uploaded images in your uploads folder. very useful:

```
// post thumbnail support
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
add_image_size( 'featured-thumb', 282, 158, true ); 
}
```